# How @classmethod works as an array?

Tags: python

Can someone please help me with the line " newcls = cls([0,0],[0,0])". It is written that it creates empty class. But how it works and why  only pair of two zeros? What if we write cls([0,0,0],[0,0,0]).I am totally new in this object oriented programming  and  don't have any idea of this particular line. The main code is little bit messy I just want to know the function of that line. Thanks in advance!!!

```
class CFLevels:
    """For calculating and fitting crystal field levels for an ion"""
    def __init__(self, StevensOperators, Parameters):
        """add Stevens operators to make a single hamiltonian matrix"""
        self.H = np.sum([a*b for a,b in zip(StevensOperators, Parameters)], axis=0)
        self.O = StevensOperators  #save these for a fit
        self.Ci = Parameters
        try:
            self.J = (len(self.H) -1.)/2
        except TypeError: pass



    @classmethod
    def Hamiltonian(cls, Hamil):
        newcls = cls([0,0],[0,0])  # Create empty class so we can just define Hamiltonian
        newcls.H = Hamil
        newcls.J = (len(Hamil) -1.)/2
        return newcls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not create an empty class but a new instance of CFLevels like CFLevels([0,0],[0,0])

Comment: So the first [0,0] denotes an empty "StevensOperators" and next [0,0] is for empty Parameters??